# Convert CEP (Brazilian ZIP code) in latitude and longitude

Tags: geolocation, location, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a dataset with several informations about some schools, in Brazil. I'd like to get the latitude and longitude from the CEP numbers (Brazilian ZIP code). Here is the dataset:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   65445 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ region     : chr  "Norte" "Norte" "Norte" "Norte" ...
 $ state      : chr  "RO" "RO" "RO" "RO" ...
 $ county     : chr  "Ariquemes" "Ariquemes" "Ariquemes" "Ariquemes" ...
 $ type_area  : chr  "Urbana" "Urbana" "Urbana" "Urbana" ...
 $ school_type: chr  "Estadual" "Privada" "Privada" "Privada" ...
 $ school     : chr  "EEEFM PROFESSORA CARMEM IONE DE ARAUJO" "CEET - CENTRO DE EXCELENCIA EM EDUCACAO E TECNOLOGIA SENAI - JOSE FERNANDES DE MOURA" "SENAC ARIQUEMES" "COLEGIO EXCELENCIA" ...
 $ school_code: num  11048620 11049375 11049758 11049910 11052406 ...
 $ cep        : num  76874026 76872838 76876674 76873524 76873743 ...
 $ lat        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ long       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look up Brasilian zip codes on Geocode.xyz. [Eg., 97576-180](https://geocode.xyz/97576-180?region=BR)